# How to avoid receiving DUE date field in Collect Feed Back Work Flow? 

Tags: workflow

I have create a share point 2010 workflow, in my form there is a optional field called Due Date which.So if i dint select any date in that it give date like 01/01/0001

Instead on that i need to hide or set have to set some text to it how to do this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you want to hide the due date field totally for your workflow that is definitely possible.

Just open up Sharepoint Designer (SPD) and your workflow. In the overview page in the lower right you see all associated Infopath forms with your workflow. When you double click these forms you can customize them and e.g. delete the due date field.

Comment: Dennis, do you think Infopath will work with SharePoint standard edition? I read blog post saying Enterprise featuer is required for infopath form customization

Comment: Yes, InfoPath Forms Services require SharePoint Enterprise. For workflow forms you might be good with SP Standard, read about it here: http://blog.sharepoint-videos.com/licensing-requirements-for-infopath-forms-on-sharepoint/